# How to use vue-i18n inside my vue-route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

1. My main app.js

   ```
           import Vue from 'vue'
           import language from './language'
           import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

           Vue.use(VueI18n)
           const i18n = new VueI18n({
             locale: 'en', 
             messages: language.messages,
           })

           import router from './router'
           new Vue({
             el: '#app',
             i18n,
             router,
             template: '<App/>',
             components: { App }  
           })
   ```
2. The language.js

   ```
           export default { 
               messages : {
               en: {
                   hello: 'hello!'
                 },
                 ja: {
                   hello: 'こんにちは!'
                 },
                 zh: {
                   hello: '你好!'
                 }
               }
           }
   ```
3. my issue is following route.js code, which I can't use `this.$i18n.t('hello')`, because `$i18n` is not available.

   ```
           import Vue from 'vue'
           import Router from 'vue-router'

           export const myRouteMap = [

             {
               path: '/',
               component: MyComponent,
               redirect: '/myHome',
               //name: 'Home',
               name: this.$i18n.t('hello') // can't use $i18n here.
             }
           ]
   ```

Is there anyone has a similar situation, want to use i18n at vue-route and resolved the issue?

Comment: `this` is not a Vue instance in that file. Why are you trying to bind the route's name to a translated variable? The name shouldn't ever change

Comment: I'm using `route.name` to display to the UI and want to change it for the different language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example `this.i18n` is not going to be defined because it is not a Vue instance in the context of that file.

Your root issue is that you are attempting to put display data in the `route`'s definition. This is bad practice in general and results in issues like the one you've run into.

The `name` property of the `route` should be a unique identifier of the route and should not change after being defined.

If you want to base a Vue instance's property off of the translated name of the route (which is still too tight a coupling for my taste) you could do that in the Vue component you specified for the route.

```
computed: {
  title() {
    return this.$i18n.t(this.$route.name);
  }
}
```

Really, though, you should not base your display data on the `route` object. Seems like it would be clearer and less work to just specify the translation message key you want to pass to `this.$i18n.t` in the definition for that related property:

```
computed: {
  title() {
    return this.$i18n.t('hello');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I notice Vue instance won't be available at that route file. Before I saw your message I moved my translate code to the navigation component.  It's kind of what you're describing. So I add another property name to route object, so `{path:'/', name = 'こんにちは', text_code='hello'}`, so my navigation code is `<div>{{$t(route_item.text_code)}}</div>`.

Comment: and what about if I want to use the language for meta titles?